# Extracting a common superclass from two UIApplicationDelegate implementations leads to a crash when trying to set the window outlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate

We have a project that builds two separate targets that have target-specific classes that implement `UIApplicationDelegate`. After extracting a superclass from the two app-specific app delegates, we find that the application crashes on launch, with an error that usually indicates a connected `IBOutlet` that does not have have a valid implementation:

> [...YYYAppDelegate... setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key
>   value coding-compliant for the key window.

The stack trace and timing of the crash is typical of this problem - clearly, we've done something that has broken the `window` property.

Prior to performing the refactor, our app delegate interfaces and implementations looked something like this:

```
@interface YYYAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
...
@end

@implementation YYYAppDelegate

// No @synthesize of window
...
@end

@interface ZZZAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
...
@end

@implementation ZZZAppDelegate

// No @synthesize of window
...
@end
```

The `window` property is auto-synthesized by virtue of our re-declaration of the `window` property from `UIApplicationDelegate` in the `@interface` block of each class.

After the refactor, things look like this:

```
@interface XXXAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation XXXAppDelegate
...
@end

@interface YYYAppDelegate : XXXAppDelegate
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
...
@end

@implementation YYYAppDelegate
// No @synthesize of window
...
@end

@interface ZZZAppDelegate : XXXAppDelegate
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
...
@end

@implementation ZZZAppDelegate
// No @synthesize of window
...
@end
```

What is going on here? Why would extracting a superclass in this way break the `window` properties?

Answer (score 1):

Property auto-synthesis does not automatically synthesize properties that are declared in a protocol - one must either re-declare them in the class's `@interface` or add an explicit `@synthesize`. However, re-declaring a protocol property in the `@interface` of a class that inherits from a class that declares conformity to this protocol does **not** lead to the property being automatically synthesized. I can't find an official statement of this, but the behavior appears consistent across several tests.

One must either re-declare the property in the basest class that declares conformity to the protocol, or add an `@synthesize` statement within the superclass, or in each of the subclasses. In our case, we resolved it by adding an explicit synthesize to `XXXAppDelegate`, like so:

```
@interface XXXAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation XXXAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

@end
```

We also removed the property re-declarations in the subclasses in the interest of cleanliness.